# toggle class to a image tag not working in ie8

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a custom select box which has an arrow. I want to rotate the arrow when a link (select box option) is clicked. In my script I added some code on that image click to toggle class `arrow_rotate`. It's working fine in all the bowers except IE8.

Note that I used `slideToggle()` in the same function for other reason and that works fine.

```
$('.show_link').click(function(){
    var img_link = $(this);
    $(img_link).toggleClass('arrow_rotate');
    $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

or

```
$(this).toggleClass('arrow_rotate');
```

css

```
.arrow_rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px!important;
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="show_link dft-link_img" src="../images/drop-down-arrow.png">
```

Comment: you dont need to wrap `img_link` with `$`, because it is already a `jQuery` object

Comment: If you're supporting IE8, one thing to ensure is that you're using the right version of jQuery - jQuery 2.x only supports IE9 and up.

Comment: @Hecksa could u tel the exact jQuery version.

Comment: @Sami - I don't know the exact version of jQuery you're using, since you haven't told us in your question. If it starts with a 2, then IE8 isn't supported. If it starts with a 1, then IE8 is supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is not with your script, its not working because `transform` property is not supported in IE8...